# mysql alter table stuck in preparing state

Tags: mysql, django, django-south, django-database

I recently tried to change a column in my database with a south migration for my django project from a CharField to a IntegerField

I did a `python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto`

i then applied the migration and it just hung. I stupidly ran this right on my production server before trying out locally. Once I tried locally I got this error in my traceback

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'pickup_id' at row 1
```

When I go into mysql workbench and just try to revert the changes back to a CharField it just hangs in the "preparing" state and eventually times out. My site just hangs wherever this table is used and I cant preform any queries on this particular table.

I'm open to any suggestion. Thank you

Comment: access the mysql console directly by doing ./manage.py dbshell, and then UPDATE script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was applying the --fake parameters to my migrate call

```
./manage migrate appname --fake
```